# How to go back to parent Template, after the child template rendered into application(root)Template

Tags: ember.js

im using ember-cli, and this is my router

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('app', function(){
        this.resource('app.requisitions',{path:'/requisitions'}, function(){
            this.resource('app.requisitions.manage', {path:'/manage'}, function(){
                this.resource('app.requisitions.manage.draft', {path:'/draft'}, function(){
                    this.route('detail',{path:'/:id'});
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

i got all of this route working properly. Even the detail route (the very last children) which is rendered to application template (the root template) using the code below, and i'm really happy with the result.

pods/app/requisitions/manage/draft/detail/route.js

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this.render({
            into: 'application'
        });
    }
});
```

in detail template, i want it to have a back button to go back to app.requisitions.manage.draft (1 parent above)

```
{{#link-to 'app.requisitions.manage.draft'}}<button>BACK</button>{{/link-to}}
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work. i am really clueless what did i do wrong.

i'm getting this error,

Error while processing route: app.requisitions.manage.draft.index Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

similar question at

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1984

seems like what im doing up there is wrong. but im still open for suggestions :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm nesting the resources because I need the nested URL, also I need to be able to use the "needs" property on the controllers to get values from parent controllers. However, I don't always want to nest the templates. Have you found any solutions to this problem since you posted this?